# pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch between 9.5.1 and 9.4.1

Tags: postgresql

I'm having problems with Postgres pg_dump due to server version mismatch, while on OSX 10.11.1.

```
$ pg_dump
pg_dump: server version: 9.5.1; pg_dump version: 9.4.1
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
$ which pg_dump
/usr/local/bin/pg_dump
$ echo $PATH
/Users/jade/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/Users/jade/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/Users/jade/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/Users/jade/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/Users/jade/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/jade/.rvm/bin
```

I installed using Brew, and reinstalled and uninstalled Postgresql several times (turning it on and off again)

I've pretty much gone through every instruction / answer in the other "pg_dump aborting because of server mismatch" - including editing my .bash_profile AND .profile to include at the top of the file with no success.

```
export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$PATH"
```

Does anyone have any advice to force the server version to move back to 9.4.1, or vice versa? Why is it being redirected to the wrong version?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Does /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/pg_dump work?

Comment: could you show the result of `which pg_dump` please?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh! So I found the problem in the end after some help.

```
$ which pg_dump
/usr/local/bin/pg_dump
```

I believe that it was because that I had a version of PG in my Cellar, which the code kept referring it. I had to redirect the pg_dump to the one in /usr/local/bin/pg_dump.

Answer (score 0):

As someone who just struggled with the same issue, here is how I solved it.

- Navigate to the location of the current Postgres Server pg_dump. For me, this was `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin`
- Copy the `pg_dump` file
- run `$which pg_dump` which for me was also `usr/local/bin/pg_dump'`
- navigate to above directory and paste the pg_dump file. Fixed my issues!